# Getting not coherent values of y position in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on Unity, and I what I would like to do is to make a model rise from below through a coroutine. The code is the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;


public class CharacterVisualization : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public IEnumerator UpRising(float finalY, float riseVelocity)
        {
            var position = transform.localPosition;
            
            while (position.y < finalY)
            {
                position = new Vector3(position.x, position.y + riseVelocity,
                    position.z);
                transform.position = position;

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I have not coherent y values in the editor and in the console (while printing), as shown in the following two images:

> Printed position inside the Unity console

[image: printed position inside the Unity console]

> Transform position and rotation inside the Unity editor

[image: transform position and rotation inside the Unity editor]

I tried using both `position` and `localPosition`, without having success. Could someone help me please?

Comment: At which moment you got the transform image? And the print? Also, take in mind that local position is your position based on your direct parent, and position is your position in the world, mixing then up can cause problems (unless the object are at root).

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between `position` and `localPosition`

The transform image has been taken at the same moment of the print. I have tried both `localPosition` and `position`, but they print the same value and this is confusing me

Comment: You dont even have a log into the shared code, how could we know when is the "same moment"

Comment: I removed all the logs in the shared code to keep it as clean as possible...
I had a `Debug.Log("position: " + position)` just before the `while`.

Comment: First, don't remove logs if you are using their result to show the problem. Second, if this show the position before the while, your statement "The transform image has been taken at the same moment of the print." isn't true, unless you took the image before running the code, if this is the case, show to us the object hierarchy that has the Script component

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up position and localPosition. Just replace `transform.localPosition` with `transform.position`

Comment: I have already tried this, but it does not work. In fact, writing `transform.localPosition` and `transform.position` gives to me the same exact position result when I print it inside the console. This is why I am so confused